# Python convert gff3 format to tab delimited format

Tags: python

I am seeking help in converting gff3 to tab delimited format in python. The gff3 format is the output of MetaGene (ORFs identification)

Here is the gff3 format

```
# 1  
# gc = 0.431382
# bacteria
203     352     +       0       5.71721 complete
630     860     -       0       5.47138 complete
1627    2106    +       0       6.34693 complete
2052    2579    +       0       10.1632 complete
2693    3025    +       0       3.34757 complete
3036    3338    +       0       12.6268 complete
3686    3988    +       0       9.13142 complete

# 2
# gc = 0.542127
# bacteria
1       750     +       0       54.861  partial (lack 5'-end)
764     1024    +       0       2.2746  complete
1166    1381    +       0       19.3387 complete
1459    1710    -       0       11.7264 complete
1740    2042    -       0       28.3932 complete
2138    2314    +       0       3.60539 complete
```

The required output should be

```
#ORF    source_DNA  start   end   strand
1.1           1      203    352     +
1.2           1      630    860     -
1.3           1      1627   2106    +
1.4           1      2052   2579    +
1.5           1      2693   3025    +
1.6           1      3036   3338    +
1.7           1      3686   3988    +
2.1           2      1      750     +
2.2           2      764    1024    +
2.3           2      1166   1381    +
2.4           2      1459   1710    -
2.5           2      1740   2042    -
2.6           2      2138   2314    +
```

Comment: Does it have to be in Python?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am running my code in Python